# View goes missing for few minutes and then reappears in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm facing this strange issue in Postgres (Hosted on Cloud SQL GCP) where a view doesn't work in Postgres for a few minutes. It get's inactive and after a while works fine.

I checked the underlying ddl and the table seems to work fine. This has been happening quite frequently and due to this our reports and dashboards show error relationship for the period when the view is inactive.

Has this happened to anyone? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What specific errors are you getting?  You describe it as both 'missing' and 'inactive', which seem to be contradictory.

Comment: Is it a materialized view?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.